# Local provider-hosted addin reachable on SharePoint?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin, provider-hosted-app

is it possible to host a web-service locally and setting it up as a provider-hosted app for a SharePoint site that is reachable over the Internet, provided that the web-service is located on the same network as the SharePoint server is hosted on?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. The PHA URL also needs to be accessible over the Internet, as well.